# Proving that there is no solution to $ x^4 + x^3 -x + 1 = 0 $ in $\Bbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that there is no solution for this equation for $x\in \Bbb R$  :

$$   x^4 + x^3 -x + 1 = 0   $$

Comment: Share some of your thoughts/work at least. But looks like you have already got answers without doing anything.

Comment: Are you supposed to know how to solve cubic equations ?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = x^4+x^3-x+1\forall x\in (-\infty,\infty)$

**For $x\geq 0$**

$\bullet\; $ If $0\leq x\leq 1\;,$ Then $f(x)=x^4+x^3+(1-x)>0$

$\bullet\; $ If $x>1\;,$ Then $f(x)=x^4+x(x^2-1)+1>0$

**For $x<0$**

Put $x=-t\;,$ Then $t>0$

$\bullet\; $ If $0<t<1\;,$ Then $f(t) = t^4+t(1-t^2)+1>0$

$\bullet\; $ If $t\geq 1\;,$ Then $f(t) = t^3(t-1)+t+1>0$

So The equation $f(x)=x^4+x^3-x+1>0\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: awesome , thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Determine the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^4+x^3-x+1$ and find the local minimum (use the second derivative test) of the function. Then show that $f(x) \to \infty$ for $x \to \pm \infty$ by using $f(x)=x^4(1+1/x-1/x^3+1/x^4)$. What can you conclude from these observations?

Edit: Use cardanos fomula to calculate the zeros, or use the same procedure as proposed here.

Comment: i can't determine when the first derivative function equal zero

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this 
$$x^4+x^3-x+1=0\\x^4+x^3=x-1\\f(x)=x^4+x^3=x^3(x+1)\\g(x)=x-1$$ plot then together ,and see there is no cross section (or no solution)
[image]